# routes pro-blem in form ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have create a sing up form in ruby and rails

I have create a form

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: "new"}  do |f| %>

            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>

            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

            <%= f.submit "Create my account",class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

        <% end %>
```

and i have write down in routes file this

```
get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
```

But when i see the out put as a html this is looking like this

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/new" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
```

It is post method how can i define get and post both in route file and how can i use action singup ?

Please help me

Comment: if no one able to give ans then query go in -1 :) so funny

Answer (score 0):

Do this on the route:

```
match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
```

Comment: where is get and post ?

Comment: Match will do that for you. It will catch the get and the post.

Comment: match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: [:get] I have write down this it working by my query is still there

Comment: <%= form_for @user, url: {action: "new"}  do |f| %> when i write down this it show me this output <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/new" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">  why is not in action singup ?

Comment: try this on the form url => url_for(:action => 'signup')

Comment: i am using 4.0  so now i have change code same which you send me <%= form_for @user, url => url_for(:action => 'signup')   do |f| %> now it's show me error :(

Comment: I have write down there <%= form_for @user, url => url_for(:action => 'signup')   do |f| %> when i see to run rake db:routes

Comment: i think this would be better in routes.rb - 
match "signup" => "users#create", :as => "signup", :via => [:get, :post]
and the user :action => :signup in the form.

Let me know if that works.